# Create a Pivot style table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure how to get what I'm trying to do across in the title, any help there would be appreciated.

Here's the problem:

I've got a large data set, currently more than 108k rows with 5 columns. I'm trying to display it in a particular way so that it will look similar to how it looks in the current Pivot table in Excel. I have the data imported into MSSQL here's a sample:

```
State   Project ClassOfPlant    Description                                         ProjApprovalDate
FL      4139904 TR              2016 CO161 OA341 SPECIAL SERVICES BLANKET           2016-10-11
FL      4144128 TR              WSSD RWB M6 GPON CARD ADDITION TO SUPPORT GROWTH    2016-10-11
FL      4145813 OP              BRND-RBB-FTTP-GFLD-CROSSINGS-FISHHAWK RANCH W PH4B  2016-10-11
FL      4146018 OP              LKLDN-TMF-GFLD 56 SFU DONOVAN RD ESTATES DESIGN     2016-10-11
```

Here is how I would like it to look when I return the results:

```
State   ClassOfPlant    Project Description                                         ProjApprovalDate
FL              
FL      TR          
FL                      4139904 2016 CO161 OA341 SPECIAL SERVICES BLANKET           10/11/2016
FL                      4144128 WSSD RWB M6 GPON CARD ADDITION TO SUPPORT GROWTH    10/11/2016
FL      OP          
FL                      4145813 BRND-RBB-FTTP-GFLD-CROSSINGS-FISHHAWK RANCH W PH4B  10/11/2016
FL                      4146018 LKLDN-TMF-GFLD 56 SFU DONOVAN RD ESTATES DESIGN     10/11/2016
```

There would be additional formatting, like lines around each column and row and different formatting on the date, but that's not important right now. I just need to find out how to pull the data so it looks right.

**EDIT**

I cannot use SSRS, I am putting this on a report website that I created. I have been able to get what I need through PHP, but it takes a long time to load and I'm not able to limit the number of rows to make use of pagination. My hope is that I can use a single query and then use pagination to make several pages and speed up the load of the pages.

Comment: Where is your SQL code? How can we identify what is wrong without posting that?

Comment: I strongly believe this is your UI thing to render it like that.  It is not back-end task

Comment: I don't have any code yet, I can't even figure out where to start.

Comment: Essentially you are trying to produce a report. Look at SSRS or some other reporting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very straight way to create nested sets is XML:

--Mockup-table

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([State] VARCHAR(100), Project INT, ClassOfPlant VARCHAR(100),[Description] VARCHAR(100),ProjApprovalDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('FL',4139904,'TR','2016 CO161 OA341 SPECIAL SERVICES BLANKET',{d'2016-10-11'})
,('FL',4144128,'TR','WSSD RWB M6 GPON CARD ADDITION TO SUPPORT GROWTH',{d'2016-10-11'})
,('FL',4145813,'OP','BRND-RBB-FTTP-GFLD-CROSSINGS-FISHHAWK RANCH W PH4B',{d'2016-10-11'})
,('FL',4146018,'OP','LKLDN-TMF-GFLD 56 SFU DONOVAN RD ESTATES DESIGN',{d'2016-10-11'});
```

--The query

```
SELECT t1.[State] AS [@value]
      ,(
        SELECT t2.ClassOfPlant AS [@value]
              ,(
                SELECT t3.Project AS [@value]
                      ,t3.[Description] AS [@desription]
                      ,t3.ProjApprovalDate AS [@apporval_date]
                FROM @tbl AS t3
                WHERE t3.[State]=t1.[State] AND t3.ClassOfPlant=t2.ClassOfPlant
                FOR XML PATH('project'),TYPE
               )
        FROM @tbl AS t2
        WHERE t1.[State]=t2.[State]
        GROUP BY t2.ClassOfPlant
        FOR XML PATH('plant'),TYPE
       )
FROM @tbl AS t1
GROUP BY t1.[State]
FOR XML PATH('state'),ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root>
  <state value="FL">
    <plant value="OP">
      <project value="4145813" desription="BRND-RBB-FTTP-GFLD-CROSSINGS-FISHHAWK RANCH W PH4B" apporval_date="2016-10-11" />
      <project value="4146018" desription="LKLDN-TMF-GFLD 56 SFU DONOVAN RD ESTATES DESIGN" apporval_date="2016-10-11" />
    </plant>
    <plant value="TR">
      <project value="4139904" desription="2016 CO161 OA341 SPECIAL SERVICES BLANKET" apporval_date="2016-10-11" />
      <project value="4144128" desription="WSSD RWB M6 GPON CARD ADDITION TO SUPPORT GROWTH" apporval_date="2016-10-11" />
    </plant>
  </state>
</root>
```

### UPDATE

You can create your result table-wise from the XML like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')=N'state' THEN nd.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') END AS [State]           
      ,CASE WHEN nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')=N'plant' THEN nd.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') END AS [ClassOfPlant] 
      ,CASE WHEN nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')=N'project' THEN nd.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') END AS [Project] 
      ,CASE WHEN nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')=N'project' THEN nd.value('@desription','nvarchar(max)') END AS [Description] 
      ,CASE WHEN nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')=N'project' THEN nd.value('@apporval_date','date') END AS [ProjApprovalDate] 
FROM @xml.nodes('//*[local-name(.)!="root"]') AS A(nd)
```

The result

```
State   ClassOfPlant    Project          Description    ProjApprovalDate
FL      NULL            NULL             NULL           NULL
NULL    OP              NULL             NULL           NULL
NULL    NULL            4145813          BRND-RBB ...   2016-10-11
NULL    NULL            4146018          LKLDN-TMF...   2016-10-11
NULL    TR              NULL             NULL           NULL
NULL    NULL            4139904          2016 CO16...   2016-10-11
NULL    NULL            4144128          WSSD RWB ...   2016-10-11
```

Use `ISNULL` to return an empty string instead of a `NULL` if you need this...

Comment: How would I get the xml from the first query into the `@xml` variable? I tried adding `declare @xml xml  insert into @xml`, but I get an error about `FOR XML` is not allowed in `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @Mike Just use `DECLARE @xml XML=(Put the query here)`. Although XML looks like table data it is a scalar value...

Comment: You could simply have this wired up in SSRS using two row groups in minutes. Which version of SQL Server are you using? There is a glorified pivot table in ssrs called a matrix.

Comment: I'm using SQL2008. But I can't use SSRS for this website.

Answer (score 1):

SQL CLI tools are not really designed for neat presentation of data. You will probably find that it is more trouble than it is worth to try to do this in SQL. For a quick solution, I would look into using [R](https://www.r-project.org/) to format the data.

Comment: I was afraid of that.