# SQL SELECT: concatenated column with line breaks and heading per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, sqlxml, for-xml-path

I have the following `SQL` result from a `SELECT` query:

```
ID | category| value | desc
1  | A       | 10    | text1
2  | A       | 11    | text11
3  | B       | 20    | text20
4  | B       | 21    | text21
5  | C       | 30    | text30
```

This result is stored in a temporary table named `#temptab`. This temporary table is then used in another `SELECT` to build up a new colum via string concatenation (don't ask me about the detailed rationale behind this. This is code I took from a colleague). Via `FOR XML PATH()` the output of this column is a list of the results and is then used to send mails to customers.

The second `SELECT` looks as follows:

```
SELECT t1.column,
       t2.column,
       (SELECT t.category + ' | ' + t.value + ' | ' + t.desc + CHAR(9) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
           FROM #temptab t
           WHERE t.ID = ttab.ID
           FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS colname
FROM table1 t1
...
INNER JOIN #temptab ttab on ttab.ID = someOtherTable.ID
...
```

Without wanting to go into too much detail, the column `colname` becomes populated with several entries (due to multiple matches) and hence, a longer string is stored in this column (`CHAR(9) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` is essentially a line break). The result/content of `colname` looks like this (it is used to send mails to customers):

```
A | 10 | text1
A | 11 | text11
B | 20 | text20
B | 21 | text21
C | 30 | text30
```

Now I would like to know, if there is a way to more nicely format this output string. The best case would be to group the same categories together and add a heading and empty line between different categories:

```
*A*
A | 10 | text1
A | 11 | text11

*B*
B | 20 | text20
B | 21 | text21

*C*
C | 30 | text30
```

My question is: How do I have to modify the above query (especially the string-concatenation-part) to achieve above formatting? I was thinking about using a `GROUP  BY` statement, but this obviously does not yield the desired result.

Edit: I use `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4270.0 (X64)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL there.)

Comment: @jarlh I believe for-xml-path is SQL server specific, we just don't know the version.  though I would think it's safe to say it's 2008+

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4270.0 (X64) (*updated in post*)

Comment: Such issues are normally not done within the DBMS but rather in an application/presentation layer... Is there a good reason to use T-SQL for this?

Comment: unfortunately, much of our _logic_ is done via T-SQL. so currently, we would need a solution for this, even though oubviously it's far from best practice. the main reason in my given example is, that the content of this column is directly used as content for an auto-generated e-mail...

Comment: alternatively, I would like to create a string which yields a nicely-formatted and aligned table in the email. I found a solution by padding the fields with spaces, but since Outlook uses Arial for displaying mails, the result is not properly aligned...

Comment: As a first shot you might read my answer about *nested sets* here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40007260/5089204. When there is bit more time and no sufficient answer yet I'll provide an answer a bit later...

Comment: I think I can start doing something with the solutin you provide in the linked thread. But one thing: you say that _You can create your result table-wise from the XML like this..._ => in my case, I need the result as a string. this is why I use `.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')` for (see above). How could I do that with your approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,category varchar(50),value int, [desc] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'A',10,'text1'),
(2,'A',11,'text11'),
(3,'B',20,'text20'),
(4,'B',21,'text21'),
(5,'C',30,'text30')

Declare @String  varchar(max) = '' 

Select @String = @String + Case when RowNr=1 Then Replicate(char(13)+char(10),2) +'*'+Category+'*' Else '' end 
                         + char(13)+char(10) + category + ' | ' + cast(value as varchar(25)) + ' | ' + [desc] 
 From (
        Select * 
              ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By Category Order By Value)
         From  @YourTable

      ) A Order By Category, Value

Select Substring(@String,5,Len(@String))
```

Returns

```
*A*
A | 10 | text1
A | 11 | text11

*B*
B | 20 | text20
B | 21 | text21

*C*
C | 30 | text30
```

Comment: I need a solution which is an adaption/extension of the `SELECT` query, which I show in my post. I think your solution does not work for that.

Comment: @beta Understood, I'll take another shot at it.

Comment: I borrowed your Table declare. Hope you don't mind. +1 from my side

Comment: @Shnugo Seriously, for what I've learned from watching your posts, you could borrow my kidney

Answer (score 0):

This should return what you want

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,category varchar(50),value int, [desc] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'A',10,'text1'),
(2,'A',11,'text11'),
(3,'B',20,'text20'),
(4,'B',21,'text21'),
(5,'C',30,'text30');

WITH Categories AS
(
    SELECT category
          ,'**' + category + '**' AS CatCaption
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY category) AS CatRank
    FROM @YourTable
    GROUP BY category
)
,Grouped AS
(
    SELECT c.CatRank
          ,0 AS ValRank
          ,c.CatCaption AS category
          ,-1 AS ID
          ,'' AS Value
          ,'' AS [desc]
    FROM Categories AS c

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.CatRank
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.category ORDER BY t.Value)
          ,t.category
          ,t.ID
          ,CAST(t.value AS VARCHAR(100))
          ,t.[desc] 
    FROM @YourTable AS t
    INNER JOIN Categories AS c ON t.category=c.category
)
SELECT category,Value,[desc]
FROM Grouped 
ORDER BY CatRank,ValRank
```

The result

```
category    Value   desc
**A**       
A           10      text1
A           11      text11
**B**       
B           20      text20
B           21      text21
**C**       
C           30      text30
```